# Android loader started on click then orientation changed - data is not provided anymore

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

As the title says it, I am starting a `Loader` on a button click and then I am doing an orientation change. In the recreated activity `onLoadFinished` is not called automatically on startup. My suspicion is that `LoaderManager` has no idea of this newly created activity instance as I don't think it's tied that much with activity life cycle. But I may be wrong ...

This is the loader, providing an array of Strings and simulating it's delaying data result with 3 seconds. Implementation is a simplified version of `AsyncTaskLoader` [sample code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

public class ContentAsyncLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String[]> {
    private String[] data;

    public ContentAsyncLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (data != null) {
            deliverResult(data);
        } else {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String[] loadInBackground() {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        final String[] result = { "Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE", "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800", "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air",
                "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro" };
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();
        onStopLoading();
        data = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(String[] data) {
        if (isReset()) {
            return;
        }
        this.data = data;
        if (isStarted()) {
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }
    }
}
```

And below is the activity that starts the loader on the button click - a `ListView` and a `Button`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, LoaderCallbacks<String[]> {

    private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        findViewById(R.id.btnSomeAction).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<String[]> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        ContentAsyncLoader loader = new ContentAsyncLoader(this);
        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String[]> loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String[]> loader, String[] data) {
        if (data != null) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, data);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

If somebody wants a clear question: how to properly make use of a `Loader` that is started on a button click so that the data is automatically re-provided when the activity is recreated?

I have some dirty work-around to fix this by keeping a flag set to true when button is clicked, save it when `onSaveInstanceState` is called and then in `onCreate` check it if present and if so call `initLoader`; but I hate to have this in such cases and when I am starting different loaders from an activity I need to keep a flag for each such loader as I tend to be lazy ... For example:

```
private boolean loaderCreated;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    findViewById(R.id.btnSomeAction).setOnClickListener(this);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        loaderCreated = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("TEMP", false);
        if(loaderCreated) {
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("TEMP", loaderCreated);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    loaderCreated = true;
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}
```

Isn't there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);` should be called `onCreate` every time if button was pressed before.

Because now after orientation `savedInstanceState` is not null and you are not asking loader about data.

And i see that you making it...;) and this is only way.

Regards

Comment: Yes, I know ... But as said, I hate to do it every time, isn't there a better way of doing it? Why doesn't `LoaderManager` know about this recreated activity?

Comment: LoaderManager don't know anything. It's activity job to ask about data, and Activity should ask only if there is such need (which means if button was pressed).

You should not name this variable `loaderCreated` but, `dataWasLoaded` or something like `iWantToSeeData` ;) that because real info is that you want to show data by pressing button

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the only method ... I would loved however that the `LoaderManager` should do this on my behalf.